# Content below home hero squishing to the left - responsive design - below 640px

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am fairly new on my adventure to web development. I am having issues with a site I am working on. I have had no issue with my responsive design untill I get to about 640px. Once I get to 640px or blow my html all squishes to the left except my home hero and navigation bar. If I set my headers width to auto. The nav bar will get to the same width of the rest of the site, but setting the home heros div width to auto, it does nothing. The home hero seems to stay the same.

Does anyone have any ideas that may be the problem? Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="I specilize in kitchen and bathgroom remodels.">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>DJW, LLC</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="logo-bar">
      <img id="logo" src="Img/logo.png" alt="DJW logo">
    </div>
    <a id="phone-number" href="tel:17271234567">727-123-4567</a>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Top</a></li>
      <li><a href="#content-wrap">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#projects">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="hero-image">
    <div id="color-overlay"> </div>
    <div class="hero-text">
      <h1>Quality Bathrooms & Kitchens</h1>
      <p>Over 35 Years of experience</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content-wrap">
    <div class="main-content">
      <h2>Quality & Professionalism Garenteed!</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et nibh vitae massa consectetur tincidunt. Aliquam turpis neque, eleifend nec rutrum quis, efficitur in erat. Nam eu leo id lacus tristique lobortis nec non nisl. Donec tincidunt id nulla
        quis convallis. Nunc ultricies mauris convallis nunc tempor commodo vitae ac nisi.
      </p>

      <h2>Custom Bathroom & Kitchen Remodels</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et nibh vitae massa consectetur tincidunt. Aliquam turpis neque, eleifend nec rutrum quis, efficitur in erat. Nam eu leo id lacus tristique lobortis nec non nisl. Donec tincidunt id nulla
        quis convallis. Nunc ultricies mauris convallis nunc tempor commodo vitae ac nisi.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="quote-form">
      <h2>Start on Your Free Quote!</h2>
      <input type="text" class="quote-input" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="number" class="quote-input" placeholder="Phone (number only)">
      <input type="email" class="quote-input" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="text" class="quote-input" placeholder="Address">
      <select class="quote-input" name="Room">
        <option selected disabled>Choose Project</option>
        <option value="Bathroom">Bathroom</option>
        <option value="Kitchen">Kitchen</option>
        <option value="Bathroom & Kitchen">Bathroom & Kitchen</option>
      </select>
      <textarea class="quote-input" cols="30" rows="6" placeholder="Type Your Message Here"></textarea>
      <a class="button quote-button" href="#"><strong>Get Your Free Quote</strong></a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="gallery-wrapper">
  <div id="projects">
    <h2>Gallery</h2>
    <div class="proj-imgs">
      <a href="#img1" class="gal-img" ><img src="/img/kitchen1.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1"><img src="/img/kitchen1.jpg"></a>

      <a href="#img2" class="gal-img" ><img src="/img/bathroom1.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img2"><img src="/img/bathroom1.jpg"></a>

      <a href="#img3" class="gal-img img-remove"><img src="/img/kitchen2.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img3"><img src="/img/kitchen2.jpg"></a>

      <div class="add-images">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-button-wraper">
      <div class="gallery-button">
        <p>Click The Arrow To See More!</p>
        <a id="arrow-button" class="button arrow-down"><i class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="about-wrapper">
    <div id="about">
      <h2>About DJW</h2>
      <p>Maecenas dignissim massa sed dignissim maximus. Praesent vel enim at lorem molestie rhoncus. Fusce vel iaculis purus, eget vehicula dui. Fusce posuere quam et quam porttitor, eget vestibulum quam malesuada. Nam pretium turpis finibus, ultricies
        risus ut, convallis dui. Sed semper gravida lorem, non faucibus tortor auctor at. Etiam eu nisl id ex elementum pellentesque blandit eget felis. Curabitur in ex in risus ultricies pellentesque. Praesent fringilla mauris mauris. Aliquam pretium,
        magna at consectetur eleifend, sem nunc lobortis ligula, id venenatis libero risus et nisl. Aenean feugiat hendrerit dui sed accumsan. Nam elementum elit sit amet dolor scelerisque elementum. Maecenas mollis erat at urna rhoncus interdum. Phasellus
        nibh est, mattis ut suscipit sed, laoreet quis justo. Fusce eleifend, quam id varius auctor, lorem justo fringilla sem, id sagittis risus leo maximus odio.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <p> Address: 123 Address RD Tampa, FL 12345 </p>
      <p> Phone: 727-123-4567 </p>
      <ul class="footer-ul">
        <li><a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Site Map</a></li>
        <li>&copy; DJW,LLC. All Rights Reserved</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


    CSS_________________________

         * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Header Navigation */
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4.5em;
  background-color: #FF2C19;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 998;
}

header ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 16.5em;
}

header li {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}


header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
}

header a:hover {
  color: red;
}

header li:hover {
  background: white;
  color: red;
}

#logo-bar {
  width: 18em;
  height: 14em;
  background: rgb(244,244,244);
  border-radius: 0 0 20em 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0,460px 0,400px 50%,0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0,460px 0,400px 50%,0 40%);
  position: fixed;
}

#logo {
  width: 6em;
  margin: .5em 0 2em 6em;
  position: fixed;
}

#phone-number {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  position: relative;
  margin: .35em 1em;
  padding: .1em .3em;
  border: .08em solid #fcfcfc;
  float: right;

}
#phone-number:hover {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  color: red;
}

/* Home Hero Section */
.hero-image {
background: url("img/bathroom.jpg");
padding: 20em;
position: relative;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
border-bottom: .15em solid black;
}

#color-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.hero-text {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 66%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#content-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 4em;
}

.main-content {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0em 4em 0em 7em;
  margin-top: 4em;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}

.main-content h2{
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: red;
}

.main-content p {
  color: #444;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}


.quote-form {
  position: relative;
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  background: #444;
  padding: 1.5em 2em 2em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  border: .2em solid black;
  border-radius: .8em;
}

.quote-form h2 {
  color: #00BBFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;

}

.quote-input {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: .7em;
  margin: .7em 0;
  border: .15em solid black;
  border-radius: .5em;
}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.quote-button {
  display: block;
  padding: .3em 1em;
  margin-top: .5em;
  color: black;
  background-color: #00BBFF;
  border-radius: .2em;
}

#projects {
  background: #444;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2em;
  padding-top: 0em;
  padding-bottom: 5em;
  display: inline-block;
}

#projects h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.5em;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.proj-imgs{
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #666, #555, #666);
  border-top: .15em solid black;
  border-bottom: .15em solid black;
  border-left: .1em solid #333;
  border-right: .1em solid #333;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


.proj-imgs img{
  width: auto;
  max-width: 32%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 16em;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}


.lightbox {
    /** Default lightbox to hidden */
    display: none;

    /** Position and style */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.lightbox img {
    /** Pad the lightbox image */
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.lightbox:target {
    /** Remove default browser outline */
    outline: none;

    /** Unhide lightbox **/
    display: block;
}

.gallery-button-wraper{
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery-button p {
  padding: 1em;
  padding-top: 3em;
  color: white;
}

.arrow-down {
  margin-bottom: .1em;
  margin-top: -.4em;
  height: .3em;
  display: block;
  color: #00BBFF;
  font-size: 6em;
}

/* This is in JavaScript Only */
.arrow-up {
  margin-bottom: .1em;
  margin-top: -.4em;
  height: .3em;
  display: block;
  color: red;
  font-size: 6em;
}

.about-wrapper {
  margin: .5em 2em;
}

#about {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  padding: 5em 8em;
  text-align: center;
}

#about h2 {
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#about p {
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

footer {
  background-color: #444;
  padding: 3em;
}

footer li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  margin-bottom: -1em;
  color: white;
  font-size: .5em;
}

footer a {
  font-family: "arial", serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .3em;
  color: white;
}

footer a:hover, footer a:focus {
  color: red;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.footer p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  color: white;
}


@media (max-width: 82rem) {
  .gal-img img {
    max-height: 14em;
    max-width: 40%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 70rem) {
  .gal-img img {
    max-height: 13em;
    max-width: 40%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 65rem) {
  header li {
    display: none;
  }

  #content-wrap {
    padding: 1.5em;
    padding-top: 2.5em;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
  }

  .main-content{
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 3em;
  }

  .main-content h2{
    padding-bottom: 1em;
  }

  .quote-form {
    position: none;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin: 2em auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
  }

  .gal-img img{
    max-height: 14em;
    max-width: 50%;
  }

  .img-remove img{
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 53rem) {
  .gal-img img{
    max-height: 9em;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .img-remove img{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries `@media (max-width: 768px){}` inside the curly braces put your one copy of total css and if you want to change the values you can change it

Comment: I am using media queries, I just updated this post to reflect all the html and css.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing the code for the actual content that floats to the left in the image or the css classes it is using. You are only showing what is being displayed normally before the content floats left. In order to thoroughly answer the question, the whole code is needed.

However, what happens if you put the entire content that is floating left inside another div whose class has css rules similar to this:

```
.text-center {
    display: inline;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is what I do this for any content I want to be centered. It overrides any other css rules that might make it float left.

Additionally, I would recommend using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). It has css rules already written for column arrangement. You simply call the right rules and it formats your columns.

Edited Answer:

Can you combine both answers given like this? Does this not work?

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .content-wrap {
    display: inline;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the post and put all my html and css in there. I am trying to do it as vanilla as I can. I will learn bootstrap later on though. 

text-align center did not work.

Comment: Unfortunetly 

@media (max-width: 768px){
  .content-wrap {
    display: inline;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

did not work. I have been racking my brain on this all morning. I am wondering if it has something to do with my home hero section.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it has something to do with my padding being to large on my home hero. I changed the padding sizes at certain resolution widths and it worked out.